# Cursor in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cursor

Please help, somehow the cursor began to select the whole letter rather than showing the cursor between the letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pressed the [insert key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) (<kbd>Ins</kbd> or <kbd>Insert</kbd>) on your keyboard and entered overtype mode.  Press <kbd>Ins</kbd> again to return to normal insert mode.

Comment: thank's , that was pissing me off , that's a life saver